# Angular test - enable button when form becomes valid

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I have such a form in my App, with a required field, and a button that becomes enabled once the field is not empty.

upload.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="Submit()">
                    <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="outline">
                      <mat-label translate>enter-name</mat-label>
                      <input matInput formControlName="name">
                    </mat-form-field>
<button mat-raised-button  [disabled]="!uploadForm.valid">Send</button>
</form>
```

And upload.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.uploadForm = new FormGroup({
       'name': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      );
   }
```

I want to test this case.

Trying this, upload.component.spec.ts:

```
   it('should be ok', waitForAsync(() => {
                let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
                fixture.detectChanges();
                fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                  let input = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[matInput]');
                  input.value = 'someValue';
                  input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
     expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button').disabled).toBeFalsy();
                    });
        }));
```

Doesn't work.

Can anyone please help me with the syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing a `fixture.detectChanges()` since the model changed. Try this:

```
it('should be ok', waitForAsync(() => {
                let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
                fixture.detectChanges();
                fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                  let input = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[matInput]');
                  input.value = 'someValue';
                  input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
                  // !! need another fixture.whenStable since some aspects of a form are asynchronous
                   fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                    // !! add a fixture.detectChanges() since the model changed
                   fixture.detectChanges();
                   
expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button').disabled).toBeFalsy();
                });
                  
             });
        }));
```

That being said, the good thing about `ReactiveForms` is that you don't need to mess around with the view. You can just play with the form and get what you want.

Something like this:

```
it('should be ok', () => {
   // !! first fixture.detectChanges() calls ngOnInit
   fixture.detectChanges();
   // !! change the model directly
   component.uploadForm.get('name').setValue('someValue');
   // !! update the view with fixture.detectChanges()
   fixture.detectChanges();
   expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button').disabled).toBeFalsy();
  
});
```

I think a test like that ^ is much easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ReactiveFormsModule in app.module like

> import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

and add
in import

> FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule

I just tried on stackblitz, and it works.